# Validate Excel file Format in SSIS package

Tags: excel, validation, ssis

I need to load a number of Excel files using SSIS package into a SQL Server table. I am able to successfully loop through and load my Excel files into my table I do not have any issue doing that, BUT as part of the task, I need to (validate)make sure, the files have a consistent format for all of received Excel files, things I need to check are:

- Number of columns should be the same.
- Data type for each column should be the same.
- Certain columns should not have null/empty values.

What do you suggest as the best way (simplicity and performance) to do this? Is using Script task / C# a good way? (the question is only about validating the Excel file format and columns data type)

Comment: How big are these files (ie. how much data), and how many files are there likely to be each time the SSIS package executes?  Me, personally, I tend to not necessarily try and put lots of "logic" into my SSIS packages - so I would probably just load data into some kind of temporary/staging table(s) on SQL Server and run some validation (probably using a stored proc) over that data.  However, if we're talking about a very large amount of data or lots of files continually loading, that may not be the most economical approach

Comment: I also notice this is a duplicate of the same question that was previously closed.  StackOverflow tends to want your question to be based on a specific problem that you're encountering - not necessarily more "philosophical" questions (for which the answer will be more based on someone's opinion - like my comment, above).  You might have better luck getting some guidance on this requirement at https://dba.stackexchange.com